# How to Use the iOS Screen Time API to get a user's total Screen Time (in an app I'm building)

Tags: ios, api, swiftui

The iOS Screen Time API (using the DeviceActivity framework) is capable of making custom Screen Time reports for users

- Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity
- Video Showing this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/

The problem is, beyond an introductory iOS Programming Class that used Dummy Data to create a sample app, I do not know what I'm doing at all.

I need to figure out how to

1. Request Authorization for a Device API like this
2. Get the total screen time from a user and display it

This seems simple and is possible, but I'm not even sure which files to put the code from the Documentation, let alone deal with real data from a User.

Here's what I have so far:

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI
import DeviceActivity




struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome to the first view")
            }
            .toolbar {
                NavigationLink(destination: APICall()) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First View")
        }
    }
}




struct APICall: View {
    @State private var screenTime: Double? = nil
    @State private var error: Error? = nil



    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "clock")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    if screenTime != nil {
                        Text("Total screen time: \(screenTime!) hours")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    } else {
                        Text("Press the button to fetch screen time")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            Button(action: fetchScreenTime) {
                Text("Fetch screen time")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding()
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                    )
            }
            if error != nil {
                Text("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchScreenTime() {
   //WHAT DO I DO FOR THIS
    }
}
```

**AuthRequest**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import DeviceActivity
import FamilyControls


@main
struct Worklog: App {
    let center = AuthorizationCenter.shared
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {Text("Hi")}
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await center.requestAuthorization(for: //WHAT DO I CALL HERE?
                        )
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed with \(error)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Apple documentation should be the first place you look. Research is a requirement in SO. Apple provided videos at WWDC when this was released.

Comment: @loremipsum the documentation's awful and has next to no examples. The videos apple provides have chunks in them where they leave out code bc they assume you already know, but said code is not explained anywhere else.

Comment: @KEcoding that is how it is when you get past the basics. But Apple does explicitly say what to put un the authorization field and does show how to create a sample report. That is what this question is all about.

Comment: @loremipsum All I'm saying is that I've read kernel documentation that's more helpful than Apple's - at least that isn't dependent on explaining what something is using more circular logic sometimes. Also, isn't this like a new API ? Part of research is being able to see others' code - code that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @loremipsum I'm not confused about anything here - I figured out what was happening here. I'm just saying it's an ass move to just tell the people the website that's used to get code snippets not to ask for example code snippets and to do their own research. What a waste of time. Also, what do you mean when you say that the answers "sitting right there in the code"? That's like asking a student who's taken precalc to just figure out calculus because technically they have all math they need to figure out the proofs themselves

Comment: When I say" it is sitting right there" I say click on the second link the OP posted watch the video for 3 minutes and 12 seconds and copy it and put it in Xcode, this isn't calculus it is quite literally copy and paste with the "Developer" app in the very first block of code they show.

Comment: @loremipsum Do you think telling someone that "research is a requirement" is going to help them? Also, they literally linked to the documentation and the article in the original post. Where do you think they got that code? They're confused about the places in the code that they commented in place of code that wasn't specified in the video or the documentation. Instead of doing center.requestAuthorization(for: .individual /* can also be .child */ ) they just wrote center.requestAuthorization(for: ...) with no explanation as to what "..." is.

Comment: that fetchScreenTime() function's probably going to require making a DeviceActivityMonitor extension and linking the target, which I think I had to figure out from the dredges of apple's forums. In conclusion I think it would be better to just not comment, because this original comment offered nothing to op.

Comment: @loremipsum I'm not saying I need help , I'm saying your comment was unnecessary and came off as super conceited.

Comment: see this documentaion with result https://kushwaha03.medium.com/the-screen-time-api-and-whats-new-in-screen-time-api-50a1404c130e

Answer (score -2):

```
do {
  try await center.requestAuthorization(
for: /* can be .individual to look at your 
       own screen time or .child if this 
       is going on a child's device */)
} catch {
print("Failed with \(error)")
}
```

In fetchScreenTime(), you're going to make an extension to your app that uses the DeviceActivityMonitor. I'll update when I figure out how they fit together